# Error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Location'

Tags: typescript

I have a `Location.ts` file containing:

`class Location {
    // ...
}`

`tsc` spits out the following:

> 1 class Location {
>
> ../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts:9249:11
>       9249 interface Location {
>       'Location' was also declared here.

How can I fix this?

Changing `class Location` to `export class Location` seems to fix it, but I don't understand why that makes a difference.

(I need dom in `tsconfig.json` : `"lib": ["es6", "dom"]` for my project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So reading the docs I figured that `class Location` attempts to declare the it in the global namespace and adding `export` makes it a 'module'.

Now `Location` is already 'reserved' in the global namespace by 'dom'.

Ergo the error. Lesson learned.